# Android working with dates and SQLite

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-calendar

I am trying to create a simple reminder app. Im just logically thinking about the process. Basically I want to be able to choose a DAY and time e.g Monday 15:00, this will trigger EVERY Monday 15:00 until it gets deleted from database. Having said that example I have questions to accomplish this process.

How will I store DAY and TIME, what type, do I need different columns in my table?
How can I compare real time DAY to current DAY, so if its Monday real time it will return ONLY Monday reminders? is this possible?

Will I need to primarly focus using calendar?

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values.

You can store date and time in the `TEXT` type of field in the following format:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`

and then use built-in [date & time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite to filter your records.

Another option is to store date & time as a time-stamp in milliseconds and write proper queries for selecting data or use Joda library for filtering or date & time transformation, but probably such solution would be less efficient and less convenient than first option.

Comment: So If I create, 3 columns.  Day, Start time, End time. could I compare the for example if the Day input was Monday, could I compare that to the current day using %Monday% to getDay from Calendar object

Comment: I think, in your case, many columns for representing date and time could be reasonable, if you want to access records for days of a week. You can even store numbers from 1 to 7 (or from 0 to 6) for representing days of a week and use less storage of database than in case of storing strings.

Comment: So how can I compare day stored in SQLite to current real life day

Comment: If you don't want to perform any additional transformations, you can store date and time in one column and number of day of a week in another column. After that you can compare stored records to current day and retrieve all records for single day of a week fast. Another option, is to use built-in SQLite date & time functions or store time-stamp in milliseconds. You can always retrieve any kind of date & time information from time-stamp (for sure via Java, but is should be also possible via SQLite - you can do some research about this topic).

Comment: Okay, how can I store the day-time in one column and compare it to current date, cant I just upload a string day e.g Monday and call calendar object to get current day and compare both string if it matches bring the data

Comment: You can solve this problem in many ways. I just gave you a few examples. You can store date & time in one column as a string or in milliseconds. You can compare data retrieved from a string or data retrieved from a time-stamp. You can choose an option which will be more suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using integer column is the easiest solution.

Just store the date in millisecond (`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`) and your good to go.

Then you just have to search on that integer to find the correct event in your database :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT whateveryouneed FROM events WHERE date_event > ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis())});
...
```

if you need to find all the event for a day , you just have to find the limits of the day in millisecond and make a query according to those limits